# Foam or Head as a tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

Should we prefer the use of the term "head" over "foam"? I think "head" is technically more correct. If so, what should our course of action be with the [foam](https://alcohol.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/foam) tag?

Should we retag [foam](https://alcohol.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/foam) questions as [head](https://alcohol.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/head)? Should [foam](https://alcohol.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/foam) be a synonym of [head](https://alcohol.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/head), or is it right out?

One concern is that casually-interested askers might be confused or unaware of the term "head" and thus make mistakes with their tagging. This is easily rectifiable, but adds a level of complexity to first-time users; especially if they're looking for the foam tag and can't find it.

Answer (score 13):

### Head as the tag, foam as a synonym for it.

Intuitively, 'head' feels like the correct term.  And regardless of which term is correct, the other should probably be set up as a synonym for it.  So, I propose Head as primary, Foam as synonym.

Comment: Agreed. The synonym method seems like the most helpful approach, and "head" should be preferred over "foam".